# How To select All Rows from a SAS data set that Match at least one value in another SAS Data set

Tags: sas

I am trying to read the ticker names of 100 stocks / ETFs from one CSV file. I have two CSV files, one contains the data for all stocks / etfs over a 90 day period. The second contains the name of the 100 stock/etf tickers I am interested in selecting. Below is my code, WORK.ETFnames is the one column data set that contains the 100 ETF names I want to select from the fulldata. How can I use this list of names to correctly select the desired data. In WORK.FULLdata the names are stored in a column called "Ticker". I have already sorted the data by type (either ETF or Stock) but cant figure out how to select the rows I am actually interested in from these tables. Thank you!

```
PROC IMPORT OUT=WORK.Fulldata
   DATAFILE="/folders/myshortcuts/myfolder/q2_2012_all.csv"
   DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
   GETNAMES=YES;
   DATAROW=2;
RUN;

PROC IMPORT OUT = WORK.ETFnames
   DATAFILE = "/folders/myshortcuts/myfolder/ETFs.csv"
   DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
   GETNAMES=YES;
   DATAROW=2;
RUN;

PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE stocks AS
   SELECT *
   from Fulldata
   where Security EQ "Stock";
QUIT;

PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE ETF AS
   SELECT *
   from Fulldata
   where Security EQ "ETF" 
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try merging the two datasets, and only accepting those that have matching "Ticker" values. I'm going to assume that the dataset ETFnames has the names stored under variable "Ticker" too.

```
  PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.Fulldata
            DATAFILE= "/folders/myshortcuts/myfolder/q2_2012_all.csv"
            DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
     GETNAMES=YES;
     DATAROW=2;
   RUN;

   PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.ETFnames
            DATAFILE= "/folders/myshortcuts/myfolder/ETFs.csv"
            DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
     GETNAMES=YES;
     DATAROW=2;
   RUN;

  PROC SORT DATA=WORK.Fulldata OUT=WORK.Fulldatasort;
        BY Ticker;
  RUN;

  PROC SORT DATA=WORK.EFTnames OUT=WORK.EFTnamessort;
        BY Ticker;
  RUN;

  DATA WORK.Partdata;
        MERGE WORK.Fulldatasort WORK.EFTnamessort(in=A);
        BY Ticker;
        IF A;
  RUN;

  PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE stocks AS
  SELECT *
  from Partdata
  Where Security EQ "Stock";
  QUIT;

  PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE ETF AS
  SELECT *
  from Partdata
  Where Security EQ "ETF" 
  QUIT;
```

As far as I can tell this will give you the desired result. You could also do a join in your PROC SQL statements instead of a MERGE, but the MERGE is easier to write IMO.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Im new to SAS and this helped me out a ton.